# How to compile "Improved pngnq"?

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors

The [Improved pngnq](http://pornel.net/pngnq) source archive does not come with a makefile (careful when unpacking, there is no top level directory).

How do I compile it on openSUSE 11.4? libpng/zlib headers and the usual C toolchain are installed.

```
pngnq$ gcc *.c
pngcomp.c: In function ‘main’:
pngcomp.c:111:37: error: ‘VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pngcomp.c:111:37: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
rwpng.c: In function ‘rwpng_read_image’:
rwpng.c:130:7: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘png_get_IHDR’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/png.h:2300:1: note: expected ‘png_uint_32 *’ but argument is of type ‘ulg *’
rwpng.c:130:7: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘png_get_IHDR’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/png.h:2300:1: note: expected ‘png_uint_32 *’ but argument is of type ‘ulg *’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use the version at [sourceforge](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/)?  It appears to be a more recent version and includes the comment:

> includes improvements made by porneL

who is the author of the changes at the page you reference.

Comment: Yes, it's usable thanks to included autoconf. +1 and accepted